# why drash with specific version causes error on deno?

Tags: deno

I'm exploring deno. I just got an issue while trying to start my (first ::) deno server, output saying "404"

server file is like:

```js
import { Drash } from "https://deno.land/x/drash@v1.0.0-rc1/mod.ts";

const server = new Drash.Http.Server({
  response_output: "application/json",
  resources: [],
});

server.run({
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 2803,
});
```

Command returned:

```
➜  helloDeno deno run --allow-net app.ts
Compile file:///home/totone/dev/solo/projects/helloDeno/app.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/http/server.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/http/http_status.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/testing/asserts.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/io/bufio.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/io/readers.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/mime/multipart.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/http/cookie.ts
error: Uncaught Error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/io/readers.ts' failed: 404 Not Found
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:736:23)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:753:7)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:753:7)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:753:7)
    at async processImports ($deno$/compiler.ts:753:7)
    at async compile ($deno$/compiler.ts:1316:31)
    at async tsCompilerOnMessage ($deno$/compiler.ts:1548:22)
    at async workerMessageRecvCallback ($deno$/runtime_worker.ts:74:9)
```

At beginning, I though that it was a bad use of `--allow-net` deno permission, but I tried once to reload server without a specific version for drash & it worked.

```
➜  helloDeno deno run --allow-net app.ts
Compile file:///home/totone/dev/solo/projects/helloDeno/app.ts
```

So the issue is near `@v1.0.0-rc1` package version. Who can help me understanding the reason of this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drash` is trying to import `https://deno.land/std@v1.0.0-rc1/io/readers.ts` (and other `std/@v1.0.0-rc1`) which does not exist.

`std` current version is `v0.51.0`.

---

You should use `drash@v1.0.0` which is the latest `drash` version and uses an existing `std` version.

```js
import { Drash } from "https://deno.land/x/drash@v1.0.0/mod.ts";
```

Comment: ah :/ 
I picked up the example on drash tutorials examples, apparently full of little errors like this. Great, thank you!